# How do I prevent Canvas color overwriting the existing pixels colors

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I am making a Discord Bot command using Canvas-Constructor where users can draw something and pick any color. The only issue I am facing is that when you draw and select a different color it overwrites the already colored pixels on the canvas.

I would like to know how to fix this problem, here is a video showing how the issue occurs:

https://streamable.com/uv8mp1

Note: Zoom Factor is set as 10.

`penx: Math.floor(10 / 2);`

`peny: this.penx;`

The command uses a JavaScript class to create and manage the canvas drawing. The code below is how the color, pen xy axis and setting the canvas pixel works and is what is affected in this problem. `sendCanvas` method simply just sends the generated image and buttons:

```js
class Drawing {
    constructor(int, size, name, brushRow, arrowRow, colorRow, bgcolor) {
        this.int = int;
        this.canvasmsg;
        this.size = size;
        this.name = name;

        this.arrowRow = arrowRow;
        this.colorRow = colorRow;
        this.realsize = size * zoomfactor;
        this.penx = Math.floor(size / 2);
        this.peny = this.penx;
        this.penstate = false;
        this.toggledColor = [];
        this.fcolor = this.fcolor || 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
        this.bcolor = bgcolor || 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';

        this.initPixels();
        this.c = new Canvas(this.realsize, this.realsize).setColor(this.bcolor).printRectangle(0, 0, this.realsize, this.realsize);
        this.drawCanvas();

        const filter = (i) => i.user.id === int.user.id;

        this.collector = int.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter });
        const self = this;
        this.collector.on('collect', async (i) => {
            if (i.user.id === this.int.user.id) {
                await i.deferUpdate();

                self.handleComponent(i);
            }
            else {
                i.reply({ content: `**Draw  |** **${this.int.user.username}** can only use the buttons and dropdown. *Sorry about that!*`, ephemeral: true });
            }
        });
    }

    stop() {
        this.collector.stop();
        this.drawCanvas(true);
        inProgress.delete(this.int.channel.id);

        const attachment = this.canvasmsg.attachments.first();

        const shareRow = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setLabel('Share on Twitter')
                    .setStyle('LINK')
                    .setURL(`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Check%20out%20my%20drawing%20made%20using%20Nate%20Bot!%20%F0%9F%8E%A8%20-%20via%20%40ntmcentral&url=${attachment.url}`)
                    .setEmoji('<:twitter:863917419625971712>'),
                new MessageButton()
                    .setLabel('Open in Browser')
                    .setStyle('LINK')
                    .setURL(attachment.url)
                    .setEmoji(''),
            );

        this.int.editReply({ content: `**Draw  |** **${this.name}** • **\`${this.size}x${this.size}\`**`, components: [shareRow] });
    }

    handleComponent(component) {
        const customId = component.customId;
        if (customId === 'drawLeft' || customId === 'drawRight' || customId === 'drawUp' || customId === 'drawDown') {
            this.movePen(customId);
            this.drawCanvas();
        }
        else if (customId === 'drawFinish') {
            this.stop();
        }
        else if (customId === 'drawBrush') {
            this.toggleBrushstate();
            this.drawCanvas();
        }
        else if (customId === 'drawColor' && component.componentType === 'SELECT_MENU') {
            this.toggleColor(component.values[0]);
        }
    }

    movePen(dir) {
        const movement = {
            'drawLeft': 0,
            'drawRight': 1,
            'drawUp': 2,
            'drawDown': 3,
        };

        const xactions = [-1, 1, 0, 0];
        const yactions = [0, 0, -1, 1];

        if ((this.penx > 0 || xactions[movement[dir]] === 1) && (this.penx < this.size || xactions[movement[dir]] === -1)) this.penx += xactions[movement[dir]];
        if ((this.peny > 0 || yactions[movement[dir]] === 1) && (this.peny < this.size || yactions[movement[dir]] === -1)) this.peny += yactions[movement[dir]];
    }

    toggleBrushstate() {
        this.penstate = !this.penstate;

        const brushRow = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setLabel('Finish')
                    .setCustomId('drawFinish')
                    .setStyle('PRIMARY')
                    .setEmoji('<:checkmark_white:925544348903424000>'),
                new MessageButton()
                    .setLabel(`Brush [${this.penstate ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}]`)
                    .setCustomId('drawBrush')
                    .setStyle(this.penstate ? 'SUCCESS' : 'DANGER')
                    .setEmoji('️'),
            );

        this.int.editReply({ components: [brushRow, this.arrowRow, this.colorRow] });
    }

    toggleColor(color) {
        this.fcolor = color;
    }

    initPixels() {
        this.pixels = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < Math.pow(this.size, 2); i++) {
            this.pixels.push(false);
        }
    }

    setPixel(x, y) {
        this.pixels[x + (y * this.size)] = true;
    }

    setCanvasPixel(x, y, color) {
        this.c.setColor(color).printRectangle(x * zoomfactor, y * zoomfactor, zoomfactor, zoomfactor);
    }

    drawCanvas(end = false) {
        if (this.penstate) this.setPixel(this.penx, this.peny);

        for (let x = 0; x < this.size; x++) {
            for (let y = 0; y < this.size; y++) {
                this.setCanvasPixel(x, y, this.pixels[x + (y * this.size)] ? this.fcolor : this.bcolor);
            }
        }

        if (!end) {
            this.setCanvasPixel(this.penx, this.peny, this.pixels[this.penx + (this.peny * this.size)] ? '#5A0000' : 'red');
            this.sendCanvas();
        }
        else {
            this.sendCanvas();
        }
    }

    async sendCanvas() {
        if (this.canvasmsg) this.canvasmsg.delete().catch(e => console.error(e));
        this.int.channel.send({
            files: [new MessageAttachment(this.c.toBuffer(), `${this.name}.png`)],
        }).then(msg => {
            this.canvasmsg = msg;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: A map, array of colors, where every rectangle pixel  Object not only has an XY position but also stores the color. Hard to tell without a [mcve]

Comment: https://0bin.net/paste/sYXa9vGJ#uX52Rfy4paABrZXTEGgRtklvRsO3VsZb5uV3-6CzMGV here is the code

Comment: I mean, you could have a buffer with already drawn values in there as soon as a draw completes. This would also be more efficient. As soon as you are done drawing, draw the current canvas into a buffer canvas, then start drawing that buffer with new content on top.

Comment: @somethinghere so what do I need to change in the code for this to get fixed?

Comment: Code has been updated.

Comment: Two more hidden canvasses, I guess. One on which the live drawing is occuring, one which contains the last draw buffer, and then you have the one that combines both. Once you are done drawing, combine them, draw it into the buffer, and repeat the process for the next draw. This will 'save' your current canvas in a buffer, giving you freedom to just ignore whatever it did. Does that help?

Comment: I tried this method, it unfortunately does not fix this problem... i've tried almost everything I could think to fix it but to no avail.